# How to see the currently loaded shared objects in Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries

I have two, related questions:

- How can I see if a shared library is currently loaded? (i.e. system-wide, process agnostic)
- How can I see all shared libraries loaded by a process?

Answer (score 71):

You can do both with `lsof`. To see what processes have a library open or mapped do:

```
lsof /path/to/lib.so
```

and to see what files (including shared libraries) a process has open and/or mapped, do:

```
lsof -p <pid>
```

Comment: That only helps if you know WHICH instance of a `.so` file is loaded.  Is it possible to list all th e`.so` files actually used by an app to find the disk path to  the one I need?

Comment: It's also better to run these commands with root rights (e.g. sudo) to aovid missing some processes

Answer (score 33):

Another way to see what's loaded in a process is by looking at the `/proc/PID/maps` file. This shows everything mapped into your address space, including shared objects mapped in.

Comment: Worked fine on my embedded ARM platform. While the BusyBox implementation of `lsof` did not have the needed functionality.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo grep libcairo.so /proc/*/maps
```

is a nice way to explore all `/proc/PID/maps` [mentioned by Rich](https://superuser.com/a/310268/128124) at once. Sample output:

```
/proc/8390/maps:7f0a9afae000-7f0a9b0bc000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8390/maps:7f0a9b0bc000-7f0a9b2bc000 ---p 0010e000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8390/maps:7f0a9b2bc000-7f0a9b2bf000 r--p 0010e000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8390/maps:7f0a9b2bf000-7f0a9b2c0000 rw-p 00111000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8466/maps:7f0a9afae000-7f0a9b0bc000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8466/maps:7f0a9b0bc000-7f0a9b2bc000 ---p 0010e000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8466/maps:7f0a9b2bc000-7f0a9b2bf000 r--p 0010e000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
/proc/8466/maps:7f0a9b2bf000-7f0a9b2c0000 rw-p 00111000 fc:00 274690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
```

Further `awk` and bash-fu can refine the output further.

This method also shows libraries opened with `dlopen`, tested with [this minimal setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/71ab01c5de024d9d97f0e2f0698cbee6c6a9c87a/shared-library/basic/dlopen.c#L16) hacked up with a `sleep(1000)` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 8):

You can run the next command by root and see a full list,

```
cat /proc/*/maps | awk '{print $6;}' | grep '\.so' | sort | uniq
```

This is for users who don't have lsof.

Comment: Why do you want the user to try that? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1319475/edit) your answer to better understanding.