# How do I know which shared libraries are loaded by an already running process?

Tags: linux, process, shared-libraries

How do I know which shared libraries are loaded by an already running process?

I'm using Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See currently loaded Shared Objects in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/310199/see-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux)

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
lsof -p <pid> | grep .so
```

you may need to install lsof (apt-get install lsof on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cat /proc/<pid>/maps
```

It shows the process memory map. A library should have `--x-` bit set in `perm`.